# Microsoft Windows WebView2 in FormsControlLibrary

Tags: c#, user-controls, class-library, webview2

I've tried using the "new" WebView2 Control inside of a custom UserControlLibrary in order to get a .dll out of it.

I've used it inside of a normal Forms App where it works flawlessly.
Just inside of a custom UserControl it just won't show.

Has anyone encountered the same issue and was able to solve it?

Or is there no way to use the webview2 inside of a user control?

Comment: *inside of a custom UserControl it just won't show*: what does that mean? What doesn't *show* and where? -- How did you package your UserControl? The Core and WinForms libraries, along with the run-time loader (WebView2Loader.dll), must be reachable from the hosting application